# How to hide header elements if core-scroll-header-panel is condensed?

Tags: polymer

My page is looking very similar to: https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-scroll-header-panel/demo.html. The only difference is that my page has the keepCondensedHeader flag set.

What I want to do now (if at all possible):
Hide the title (or any one of the elements shown in the condensed header) if the header is condensed.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that the `condenses` attribute only reflects in the css properties `transform` and `opacity`. That makes it hard, if not impossible to create a proper selector for the header in its condensed state. You may have to modify the source, e.g., add a class to the `core-toolbar` or `.core-header` elements when fully condensed. EDIT: You also could listen to the `core-header-transform` event, check if the header height equals `condensedHeaderHeight` and then hide your elements.

Comment: @idleherb, your edited answer was very close - except the header height stays the same all the time, it's the `y` that changes. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the javascript inside the demo file gives a very good hint of how something like this can be done easily.

I copied the whole html and js here with two more lines that hide the title when the header is condensed.

The reason that why I put <s>`128`</s> `m` as the *translate Y* is because the max header height is <s>`192`</s> `d.height` and the condensed height is <s>`64`</s> `d.condensedHeight`. When the header is condensed, it travels in y axis for a distance of <s>`128`</s> `m` (<s>`192 - 64`</s> `d.height - d.condensedHeight`).

```
<body unresolved>
    <core-scroll-header-panel condenses keepcondensedheader>
        <core-toolbar class="tall">
            <core-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></core-icon-button>
            <div flex></div>
            <core-icon-button icon="search"></core-icon-button>
            <core-icon-button icon="more-vert"></core-icon-button>
            <div class="bottom indent title">Title</div>
        </core-toolbar>
        <div class="content">
            <sample-content size="100"></sample-content>
        </div>
    </core-scroll-header-panel>
    <script>
        // custom transformation: scale header's title
        var titleStyle = document.querySelector('.title').style;
        // added code - here we need to obtain the title div as well
        var title = document.querySelector('.title');

        addEventListener('core-header-transform', function (e) {
            var d = e.detail;
            var m = d.height - d.condensedHeight;
            var scale = Math.max(0.75, (m - d.y) / (m / 0.25) + 0.75);
            titleStyle.transform = titleStyle.webkitTransform =
                'scale(' + scale + ') translateZ(0)';

            // added code - here we hide the title when the header is condensed
            title.hidden = d.y == m;
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!

---

**Update**

Actually now that I think about, it's probably a better idea to animate the `opacity` of the `title` rather than show/hide it. It would give much better user experience along with `core-scroll-header-panel`'s smooth scrolling and fading background!

Thanks to `core-animation` it's quite straight forward.

First we need to include this reference.

```
<link rel="import" href="../core-animation/core-animation.html">
```

Then the definition of the fade in & out animations.

```
<body unresolved>
    <!--define the opacity animations-->
    <core-animation id="out" fill="forwards" duration="400">
        <core-animation-keyframe>
            <core-animation-prop name="opacity" value="1"></core-animation-prop>
        </core-animation-keyframe>
        <core-animation-keyframe>
            <core-animation-prop name="opacity" value="0"></core-animation-prop>
        </core-animation-keyframe>
    </core-animation>
    <core-animation id="in" fill="forwards" duration="400">
        <core-animation-keyframe>
            <core-animation-prop name="opacity" value="0"></core-animation-prop>
        </core-animation-keyframe>
        <core-animation-keyframe>
            <core-animation-prop name="opacity" value="1"></core-animation-prop>
        </core-animation-keyframe>
    </core-animation>
```

Lastly, we call them inside the `core-header-transform` handler.

```
// animation variables
var fadeIn, fadeOut;
// create a local bool to ensure the 'fade in' animation is only called once
var condensed = false;

// retrieve the animations and set their targets
addEventListener('polymer-ready', function (e) {
    fadeOut = document.getElementById('out');
    fadeOut.target = title;

    fadeIn = document.getElementById('in');
    fadeIn.target = title;
});

addEventListener('core-header-transform', function (e) {
    var d = e.detail;
    var m = d.height - d.condensedHeight;
    var scale = Math.max(0.75, (m - d.y) / (m / 0.25) + 0.75);
    titleStyle.transform = titleStyle.webkitTransform =
        'scale(' + scale + ') translateZ(0)';

    // when the header is condensed, we fade it out
    if (d.y == m) {
        condensed = true;
        fadeOut.play();
    }
    // otherwise, we fade it back in
    else {
        if (condensed) {
            condensed = false;
            fadeIn.play();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That helped immensely. And now I am kinda embarrassed I didn't see it myself. Probably a case of starring at the forest for too long and not seeing the trees anymore. Thank you very much for the Gibbs-Headslap. :)

Comment: I just noticed that this isn't browser consistent, which is because the header has different heights. Eg: `(d.y == 112)` works for chrome on android. `title.hidden = (d.y == 128) || (d.y == 112);` seems to work on all tested Browsers though (Chrome & Firefox, Mobile & Desktop).

Comment: Here is a generic solution: `title.hidden = (d.y == m);`

Comment: Oh now I'm embarrassed! The variable was there but I chose to ignore it. :) I will update the answer.

Comment: Nice additions in your animation update, however, they are incomplete and do not work as posted here :)
To fix an uncaught reference error you need to define `condensed` as global like this: `var condensed = false;`.
You are also missing `var fadeOut = document.getElementById('out');` and `var fadeIn = document.getElementById('in');` as well as setting the animation target for those animations. `fadeOut.target = title; fadeIn.target = title;`
See https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animation

Comment: Ah oops I got it working in my sample project but forgot to copy that piece over, let me add it back in.

Comment: OK, done! Note that I retrieve the animation instances within the `polymer-ready` callback.

Comment: `Note that I retrieve the animation instances within the polymer-ready callback.` is that really needed? There is no mention of it on https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animation and it works fine doing it in the global script-scope.

Comment: I think it's safer this way as it ensures polymer related cont my is loaded.

Comment: The title is just a div isn't it? Something along the lines of `<div class="title">Title</div>`. That has nothing to do with Polymer, has it?

Comment: Not the title, see I retrieved the animation instances inside the callback. They are from polymer

Comment: True. Well it won't hurt I guess. Was just interested in that :) created is also first in the Polymer life-cycle iirc, so it shouldn't have a notable impact on performance.

Comment: One more thing (sorry ^^) but wouldn't `titleStyle.opacity = 1.0 - (d.y / m);` look better? It will fade away the title in the same manner as it does the header. Personally I like that more, since it is inline with the rest of the fade-away animation and scroll dependent.

Comment: That's another option. I was actually thinking to create an animation group that also animates the translate y of the title. Imagine while it's faded out it's also flying up a bit; while it's faded in it's coming down from top. Maybe something worth looking into.